# Remove null values from complex data structure in Groovy or Java

Tags: recursion, groovy, data-cleaning, linkedhashmap

#### I need to remove the null key values from a complex LinkedHashMap:

Here's a simple Example:

- Input

```
[f1:abc, f2:xyz, f3:lmn, test:null, people:[[name:James, City:Atlanta], [name:Rachel, City:null]], person:[name:James, Phone:4045555555, test:null]]
```

- Desired Output:

```
[f1:abc, f2:xyz, f3:lmn, people:[[name:James, City:Atlanta], [name:Rachel]], person:[name:James, Phone:4045555555]]
```

I'm already half way there, I'm just stuck on removing the nulls from the List (people). Here's what I have so far:

```
def removeNullValues(Object map) {
    map.collectEntries { k, v -> [k, v instanceof Map? removeNullValues(v) : v]}
            .findAll { k, v -> v != null}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use polymorphism to select a different method depending on whether the item is a list, map, or other:

```
def input = [
   f1:'abc',
   f2:'xyz',
   f3:'lmn',
   test:null,
   woo:[1, 2, null, 3],
   people:[
      [name:'James', City:'Atlanta'],
      [name:'Rachel', City:null]
   ],
   person:[name:'James', Phone:'4045555555', test:null]
]

def removeNulls(other) {
    other
}

def removeNulls(List list) {
    list.findResults { removeNulls(it) }
}

def removeNulls(Map map) {
    map.findAll { k, v -> v != null }.collectEntries { k, v ->
         [k, removeNulls(v)]
    }
}

println removeNulls(input)
```

Which will print:

```
[f1:abc, f2:xyz, f3:lmn, woo:[1, 2, 3], people:[[name:James, City:Atlanta], [name:Rachel]], person:[name:James, Phone:4045555555]]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is awesome!